# How to "Extract Parameter Object" with IntelliJ in Kotlin code?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, jetbrains-ide

IntelliJ has the option to refactor parameters into a object. ([Extract Parameter Object Dialog](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/extract-parameter-object-dialog.html))

I tried selecting the parameters, selecting the method and so on, but i don't get the option to extract the parameters into  a object. Trough search everywhere, it is possible to select the action, but then nothing happens. Also under the Refactor menu item, it shows the option, but it is always greyed out.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The refactoring is not implemented for Kotlin. You can vote for [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20200) to get notified when it is implemented.